# Previous/Next custom post links within custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have seen this issue in quite a few threads so apologies if I've replicated an issue here but I've had no joy in attempting to implement the solutions I have found.

I have a custom post type: `show`, to which is assigned a custom taxonomy: `show_status`. This can be set either to `current` or `past`.

In the `single-show.php` template of my theme I have placed the following:

```
<div class="newerlink"><p><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next &rsaquo;', $in_same_term = true, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'show_status' ); ?></p></div>
<div class="olderlink"><p><?php previous_post_link('%link', '&lsaquo; Previous', $in_same_term = true, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'show_status' ); ?></p></div>
```

I want the user to be able to navigate within shows categorised as `current` OR as `past` but not to move from one type to the other.

I have tried several versions of these links and all show either no links at all or links which do not differentiate between the `show_status` and pass from post to post without stopping. All have been variants on the basic:

```
<div class="newerlink"><p><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next &rsaquo;', TRUE ); ?></p></div>
<div class="olderlink"><p><?php previous_post_link('%link', '&lsaquo; Previous', TRUE ); ?></p></div>
```

I imagine I haven't quite got it right yet. I've also tried [this method](http://bucketpress.com/next-and-previous-post-link-in-same-custom-taxonomy), which rendered links but didn't respect the change in `show_status` either.

The loop in `single-show.php` is as standard in a post template:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    // content
<?php endwhile; ?>    
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Where different content is needed by category I am using:

```
<?php if (has_term('current', 'show_status')) { ;?>
```

or

```
<?php if (has_term('past', 'show_status')) { ;?>
```

to differentiate.

How can I get this to work as intended?

Comment: Do you use these linkы inside the Loop as should be the case?

Comment: Yes these are the last thing to happen before the loop's `endwhile` command.

Comment: Oh dear! I've missed this. You can't use the hyphen in a taxonomy name! That's may be the reason. Use underscore `_`.

Comment: ah - good to know, thanks. however, i've changed the taxonomy to `show_status` and adjusted all templates accordingly but am seeing the same problem with the above links (obviously altered to match).

Comment: and i get no links at all if using `<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next &rsaquo;', TRUE ); ?>`

Comment: I don't how do you query (loop through) the custom post type, so I have a proposal: try to use `taxonomy-show_status-current.php` and `taxonomy-show_status-past.php` using the native Loop instead of `single-show.php`.

Comment: i'm looking at single post templates here - according to the [wp template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) those files are for archives i think.

Comment: I can't imagine how do you differentiate between `current` and `past` in `single-show.php`. Can you show the query code you use?

Comment: yes, see edited question above. thanks for your persistence - should we move this into a proposed answer?

Comment: How do you switch between terms? I mean how WordPress knows that it's the right term? Taxonomy is OK, but term?

Comment: yes i see what you mean - in fact i have now solved this, i'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this, with some steering in the right direction in the comments under my question, by specifying different templates for different taxonomy terms using `single-show.php` to divert as follows:

```
if ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); rewind_posts(); }
    if (has_term('current', 'show_status')) {
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-show-current.php');
    }
    elseif (has_term('past', 'show_status')) {
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-show-past.php');
    }
    else {
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-default.php');
    }
```

Then, in the `single-show-current.php` and `single-show-past.php` templates I specified navigation based on term rather than taxonomy, as pointed out by Max, above (thank you for the help getting here).

The solution is based on [this code at Bucket Press](http://bucketpress.com/next-and-previous-post-link-in-same-custom-taxonomy).

```
$postlist_args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'orderby'         => 'menu_order title',
    'order'           => 'ASC',
    'post_type'       => 'show',
    'show_status'    => 'current'
    ); 
    $postlist = get_posts( $postlist_args );
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($postlist as $thepost) {
        $ids[] = $thepost->ID;
    }   
    $thisindex = array_search($post->ID, $ids);
    $previd = $ids[$thisindex-1];
    $nextid = $ids[$thisindex+1];
    if ( !empty($previd) ) {
        echo '<div class="olderlink"><p><a rel="prev" href="' . get_permalink($previd). '">&lsaquo; Previous</a></p></div>';
                        }
    if ( !empty($nextid) ) {
        echo '<div class="newerlink"><p><a rel="next" href="' . get_permalink($nextid). '">Next &rsaquo;</a></p></div>';
    }
```

Finally, to make this user-proof I installed the [radio buttons for taxonomies](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/radio-buttons-for-taxonomies/) plugin and applied it to this post type, effectively reducing the number of possible assignations to 1.